# Having issues with reading data from form-data in Next js

Tags: api, file-upload, next.js, multer

Good evening everyone. Today I tried writing a code to add a user to mongodb database which requires the following fields - name, email, accessType, password and image - but unfortunately I have been having issues uploading images with the Next js api route. I have googled for hours and no result. I disabled the bodyParser to allow files to be read but that only made things worst. It could no longer read any data at all from the req.body. I am currently using postman for testing the API. I will be very grateful if someone could please help me out before I lose my mind.

```js
import multer from "multer";
import dbConnect from "/utils/dbConnect";
import path from "path";
import Manager from "/models/Manager";

dbConnect();

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
}

const manager = async (req, res) => {
    const {method} = req;
    const { name, email, accessType, password } = req.body;
    // const { filename } = req.file;
    // console.log(filename);
    console.log(name, email, accessType, password, "values");

    switch(method) {
        case "POST":
            try {

            }
            catch(error) {

            }
            res.status(200).json({success: true, name});
    }
}

export default manager;
```

Comment: Please add an example of how you request this endpoint. You import multer but I don't see you use it?

Comment: Yh that was because I removed it when I was trying to debug it. What I just need is for the api to read form data sir

Comment: I wrapped the manager function with a higher order component and tried the file upload but the api also could not read form data